# C++ master/slave register model

Tags: c++, c++11, operators, forwarding

I'm looking forward to implement a master/slave register model template for any type in C++. I've started with:

```
template <typename T>
struct Reg {

  Reg() {}

  Reg& operator = (const T& d) {
    this->d = d;
    return *this;
  }

  Reg& operator = (const Reg& r) {
    d = r.q;
    return *this;
  }

  operator T& () {
    return q;
  }

  void update() {
    q = d;
  }

  T d; /** input */
  T q; /** output */

};
```

### The idea

When making assignment to a Reg instance the idea is to write to `d`, but when reading from the Reg instance the idea is to read from `q`, for any type T, either intrisic or user defined class.

### The problem

When using for example `T` = `int` it works fine, but when using `T` of a user defined type, for example std:complex, it fails.

#### Example

```
Reg<int> a;
a = a + a; // work fine

Reg<complex<int> > b;
b = b + b; // no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘b + b’
```

I was expecting the compiler to choose `Reg::operator T&` before `complex<int>::operator +` as it does with `T` = `int`. The first solution was to write all the C++ operators inside Reg to forward these to `d`. Is there a better solution?

#### Second problem after the previous solution (forwarding the operators)

```
Reg<complex<int> > rc1;
complex<int> c2;
rc1 + c2; // work fine
c2 + rc1; // no match for ‘operator+’ in complex<int>
```

### Global question

Is there a general solution to forward all the operators (in read mode) applied to a Reg instance to the `d` object, and to automatic cast the Reg instance to `d` type when making operation with `d` type objects?

Solutions using C++11 are also taking into account :)

Comment: Relying on `operator T& ()` is a bad idea, especially for your use case. Consider implementing the operators for `Reg` manually, avoid implicit conversions if possible.

Comment: I forgot to mention, but you might be interested in checking out Boost.Operators (or my df.operators), see my profile for links. The technique could probably be extended to cover your use case and might give you the necessary ideas and guidelines.